# SQL convert single int to a time value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to convert a single integer which represents the hour value into a time. I've tried using cast but this converts the value to a date

```
cast(datepart(hh,tstart) as datetime) as test
```

I've also tried casting it as a time and the conversion is not allowed.

The numbers I am working with are 7,8,9,10,11,12,13,...,23, 0

The format I would like is convert 7 to 7:00, 23 to 23:00, etc

Thank you

Comment: Note: Your current cast will return a datetime between '1900-01-01' and '1900-01-24' because casting X to datetime (where X is an int) just adds X days to '1900-01-01'. There are a few options you have, but one is to do something like `CAST(DATEADD(HOUR, DATEPART(HH, tstart), 0) AS TIME)`

Comment: the format you give is an output-format, and that is varchar not time. so why not just stringconcatenate your int with + ':00'?

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do that:

```
WITH table_name AS
(
    SELECT * FROM (VALUES
    (1),(2),(3),(10),(23)
    ) T(H)
)
SELECT DATEADD(HOUR, H, 0) DateValue,
       CONVERT(time, DATEADD(HOUR, H, 0)) TimeValue,
       CONVERT(varchar(2), H)+':00' TextValue
FROM table_name T1
```

I would recomend storing value as `TIME` datatype.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
select cast(dateadd(hour,3,'00:00:00') as time)
```

which gives result:

```
03:00:00.0000000
```

Use your int values in place of 3 in above statement

Answer (score 0):

Use convert `datetime` to varchar datatype and use case statement

```
DECLARE @date datetime ='2016-05-01 10:00:000'


SELECT CASE cast(DATEPART(hh,@date)as varchar(10)) 
        WHEN '10'then '10:00'
        WHEN '11'then '11:00'
        WHEN '12'then '12:00'
        .
        .
        .
        WHEN '23' then '23:00'
 END 'Hourpart'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can concatenate a minute to the time and cast it to time

```
select cast(concat(20,':00') as time(7)) as 'time'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to display like 'HH:MM',use the below query.

```
SELECT CAST(23 AS VARCHAR(50))+':00'
```

If you wanted to get the result as time format,use the below query.

```
 SELECT CAST(CAST(23 AS VARCHAR(50))+':00:00' AS TIME)
```

OR

```
SELECT CAST(DATEADD(HOUR,23,'00:00:00') as time)
```

here is the sample output :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all of your potential values are integers between 1 and 24, I think FORMAT is the simplest way.

```
FORMAT(tstart*100,'00:00')
```